# Puppeteer iterates through all pages but browser won't close after

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

After the program iterates through all pages, it doesn't break out of the while loop and closes the browser. Instead, it ran through the while loop one extra time and gave me an error: `` "TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.pager .next a` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded" `` What went wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://books.toscrape.com/");

  let isLastPage = false;

  while (!isLastPage) {
    await page.waitForSelector(".pager .next a");
    isLastPage = (await page.$(".pager .next a")) === null;

    await page.click(".pager .next a");
  }

  console.log("done");

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in the `while()` loop.  First you do `await page.waitForSelector(".pager .next a");` which will reject if it's not found.  Then, on the next line, you try to do `isLastPage = (await page.$(".pager .next a")) === null;`.  But, that will never be `null` because you just found it on the previous line of code or execution wouldn't get here.  So, I'm quite confused as to what you were trying to do here.

Comment: This site is 100% static last I checked, so there's no need for Puppeteer. Just use fetch/cheerio. That said, jfriend00's advice is good. Remove `await page.waitForSelector(".pager .next a");` and you should be good. If you want to make sure the browser closes even if an error occurs, use a `finally` block.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to iterate through every available page by clicking the "next" button and on the last page when the "next" button is not there anymore, the browser closes.

Answer (score 2):

Your last page detection logic is just flawed.  While you're on a page, you're trying to both see if ".pager .next a" exists AND you're trying to click that.  Obviously if it doesn't exist, you can't click it.

What you want to do is make sure the page is loaded by waiting for `.pager .current` which is a part of the navigation footer that will be there on every page.  Then, check if `.pager .next a` is there BEFORE you click and if it's not there, then you can just `break` out of the `while` loop.  If the page is dynamic and you need to use puppeteer, then you can do something like this:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("http://books.toscrape.com/");

        let cntr = 0;

        while (true) {
            await page.waitForSelector(".pager .current");
            console.log(`page ${++cntr}`);

            // process the page content here

            if ((await page.$(".pager .next a")) === null) {
                break;
            }
            await page.click(".pager .next a");
        }

        console.log("done");
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

And, to make sure that you always close the browser even upon errors, you need to catch any errors and make sure you close the browser in those conditions.  In this case, you can use `try/finally`.

If the page is not dynamic, then you can also just use plain GET requests and use cheerio to examine what's in the page which is simpler and doesn't involve loading the whole chromium browser engine.